# Relationship between どゆこと and どういうこと

Tags: words, colloquial-language, spoken-language, contractions

I came across the expression "どゆこと" in the show "世界の日本人妻は見た!". For example, at [21:12](https://youtu.be/aA8xWnGSA0A?t=21m12s) in an episode involving a Mongolian husband.

The phrase is also mentioned in the [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E5%A6%BB%E3%81%AF%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9F!) about the show:

> なお、2012年4月8日19:00 - 20:54に『爆笑問題の世界の日本人妻は見た! 海外生活真相リポート どゆこと?[1](https://youtu.be/aA8xWnGSA0A?t=21m12s) 異国の珍体験』という単発の特別番組（以下「パイロット版」と略記）が放送されている。

Also, a google search for "どゆこと" gets matches unrelated to the show,

A native speaker has told me that "どゆこと" is the same as "どういうこと", which means "what does it mean?", except that the latter is "correct" and the former isn't.

What's the relationship between the two? Is "どゆ" kind of like a lazy or fast way of saying "どういう"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どゆこと is a shortening of どういうこと. 言う is often pronounced ゆう and the ゆ appears in all sorts of inflections of いう, like ゆえない for いえない or ゆって for いって etc.

TV subtitles often use spellings that are supposed to reflect words as they might be spoken, like どゆこと or やってます for やっています or やだ for いやだ.

In the case of どゆこと it conveys maybe a little extra surprise, because it's shorter and thus faster than どうゆうこと, but most of all it's supposed to be "light" because of its informal character.

Comment: +1, but "a little surprise" may be an understatement. どゆこと almost always comes with a surprise or an intention of *tsukkomi*. "What'd you say!?", "Unbelievable!" or "Nonsense!" may be closer to this. どゆこと frequently appears in stand-up comedies and gag manga.