# Difference in meaning for どういうこと

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

If you say `どういうこと`, as ど\ういうこと, when asking a question, I think it just asks for an explanation (possibly followed by a quick rise on that last mora).

But when someone already knows what is going on (they're just a little confused), does it happen that it sounds more like どういうこと￣? Like here:
https://vocaroo.com/1mSKgQHbjjyw

[Original video(48:35)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AjmuPP92Zk&ab_channel=%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A8%E3%80%82)

This isn't the first time I've heard it like that. Does the pronunciation switch like that, or am I not hearing the drop in pitch right? Or is there something else?

Is the meaning different too?

Comment: Maybe similar question: [25197/relationship-between-どゆこと-and-どういうこと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25197/relationship-between-どゆこと-and-どういうこと/)

Comment: @dungarian that seems like that actually. Do you know if it is different in terms of the accent though? I simply searched " どゆこと　イントネーション" and found https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10258802125, but can't access it so I don't if theres an answer there.

Comment: Short answer is, you're hearing correctly as they tend to be voiced differently. In terms of accent alone, it depends on the person I think. It's impossible to accurately explain rhythm, pitch, and accent by text markup so I'm sorry that I can't further explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it as a somewhat intentional use of a non-standard pronunciation. The non-standard version can be written どゆこと instead of どういうこと. Perhaps a dialect might have affected it originally, but I'm not too sure about that.

It may bring a more conversational and immature tone and may indicate "I'm genuinely saying/asking this", but the meaning remains basically the same: "why? how come?"